# Change only a part of filename

Tags: python, filenames

I have these images in my folder:

- area11.tif
- area12.tif
- area14.tif
- area21.tif
- area22.tif
- area25.tif

How can I change only the last digit so they became ordered and "more incremental" ?
Instead if `area14.tif` it should be `area13.tif` and the same thing for area22/area25.

I have a code but it's a bit broken because it delete some files (it's strange, I know...).

EDIT: added (maybe broken..) code

```
try:
    path = (os.path.expanduser('~\\FOLDER\\'))
    files = os.listdir(path)

    idx = 0
    for file in files:
        idx =+ 1
        i = 'ex_area'
        if file.endswith('.tif'):
            i = i + str(idx)
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.tif'))
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
```

Comment: Why do you care? Can't you just use glob?

Comment: I care because I need them to be ordered like this for the process that following after.
Right now I am reading something about regex..Could be the way ?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Renaming files in general or specifically making them numbered sequentially?

Comment: @Mark only the last number. They must mantain the original name, just the last digit have to be incremental. Thanks.

Comment: @Link If you try to rename without having temp file, surely it will delete the existing file with same name. Better to have temp file first and then do your processing.

Comment: @john do you mean a copy of the file ?

Comment: @Link Yes, first move those files like temp_1.tif, temp_2.tif in-order and then change whatever name you want. This will avoid collision between the file names.

Comment: What's your plan for when you have 10+ files? Increment the 2nd digit too?

Comment: @DevBot the answer could be yes, but for now it don't produce more than 4/5 file for every kind of area (area1-area2, etc..). So the problem of more files don't exist right now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Read the files names in the directory into array (of strings).
2) Iterate over the array of filenames
3) For each filename, slice the string and insert the index
4) Rename

For example:

```
import os
import glob

[os.rename(n, "{}{}.tif".format(n[:5], i)) for i, n in  enumerate(glob.glob("area*"))]
```

Comment: I try to use comprehension when i actually use the produced list afterwards.

Comment: @DavisHerring updated for the sake of ease of reading. Thanks

Comment: @VladLyga it increments just the last digit of area2. Maybe I am doing something wrong..double-checking right now..

Comment: @Link please double check, and make sure you run it in the same directory (you can just run through the python repl.). I created the files like you specified in your question and checked. This should work 100%

Comment: What the {} means ? Are placeholders (if yes, for what) ?

Comment: @Link Yes it’s a placeholder for the first part of the file name and the index increment. It’s part of the python format mini language for string formatting  with “format”

Comment: @Link please see here https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: It gives me Access Denied - [WinError 5] when I try to put full path in glob.glob.. Also this `ex_area11.tif' -> 'C:\\Us0.tif'` in Traceback

Comment: Naturally you would need appropriate permissions for the directory. Maybe copy files to Test directory, open terminal, cd into Test dir, then type python (to enter the REPL ) and paste my code there. Check results. Make sure you have all permissions for Test dir AND the files.

Comment: @VladLyga: I didn't think about it being only for side effects.  I just use a `for` _statement_ in that case unless there's a named function to use.

Answer (score 1):

First you get the list of the images pathes with the glob module :

```
images = glob.glob("/sample/*.tif")
```

then you just rename all of them with the os module :

```
for i in range(len(images)): os.rename(images[i], ‘area’+i+’.tif’)
```

Comment: Does the last digit increment this way ?

Comment: Prefer `enumerate` to `len(range(...))`.

Comment: @Link please check my answer with last digit incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

First rename all filename to temp name and then add whatever name you prefer

```
import glob,os
images = glob.glob("*.tif")
for i in range(len(images)):
        os.rename(images[i], 'temp_'+str(i)+'.tif')

tempImages = glob.glob("temp*.tif")

for i in range(len(tempImages)):
        os.rename(tempImages[i], 'area'+str(i+1)+'.tif')
```

Comment: what if I want to do it without temp files ? it would work the same way ?

Comment: @Link If you do without temp file there may be possible for filename collision. That is the reason for the file delete which you mention "it delete some files (it's strange, I know...)". Seems it is trying to rename the existing file. For example: If you have 22 files when index match with 22 on some other file. It will rename the area22 file with that file.

Answer (score 1):

Found also this other solution. But there is a small difference in this one, and a better way of do the job in the end (at least for me): create a folder for each area. So simple I didn't think of it before...

BTW, here is the code, commented. I am using this one just because I achieved what I want. Thanks to all who answered, made me learn new things.

```
path = (os.path.expanduser('~\\FOLDER\\AREA1\\')) #select folder
files = os.listdir(path)

i = 1 #counter
name = 'area' #variable which the file will take as name

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.tif'): #search only for .tif. Can change with any supported format
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, name + str(i)+'.tif')) #name + str(i)+'.tif' will take the name and concatenate to first number in counter. #If you put as name "area1" the str(i) will add another number near the name so, here is the second digit.
        i += 1 #do this for every .tif file in the folder
```

It's a little bit simple, but because I put the files in two separate folders. If you keep the files in the same folder, this will not work properly.

EDIT: now that I see, it's the same as my code above....